# Laravel docker image unable to change permission to /var/www/storage/logs/ always is root owner

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, permissions

I have the next Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Add docker php ext repo
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

# Install php extensions
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd memcached

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev \
    nginx

# Install supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy code to /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

# add root to www group
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

# Copy nginx/php/supervisor configs
RUN cp docker/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
RUN cp docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/app.ini
RUN cp docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# PHP Error Log Files
RUN mkdir /var/log/php
RUN touch /var/log/php/errors.log && chmod 777 /var/log/php/errors.log

# Deployment steps
RUN composer update
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/docker/run.sh"]
```

and this is always adding root permission to the /var/www/storage/logs directory.

[image]

Here all seems to be ok, but when I did ls -l !Surprise! the logs/laravel.log file has root permission:

[image]

And when I tried do login by using postman here is the error:

```
<!-- The stream or file &quot;/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log&quot; could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file &quot;/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log&quot; could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I don't know what to do to prevent this problem guys, if you have any idea to fix this problem I will appreciate it.

I have tried to add it:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw storage
```

But the logs/laravel.log file always has root permission. Why happens it?

thanks so much.

Comment: Do not run `composer update` and then `composer install`. NEVER run `composer update` unless you are literally updating something. If you just want to get the packages always use `composer install` because you are going to get a new package (maybe) and not what it is locked on `composer.lock`...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you forgot to change user to `www` before starting the app, and Laravel is creating all files under `root`

```
# Here it goes
USER www

# Deployment steps
RUN composer update
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
RUN chmod +x /var/www/docker/run.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But I didn't mention in this question that I also have supervisord running: check this: https://github.com/alcarazolabs/laravel-9-docker-image/blob/master/docker/supervisor.conf then now I have added the user=www-data to each program starting from [group:laravel-worker] and inside of it I have added user=www-data It seems that if we don't put on there an user by default root user will starts filling with logs the laravel.log file and with root permission.

Comment: Yes, correct. So now everything is ok?

Comment: I fixed it adding the user, but now the laravel app is unable to connect to my postgresql database running on windows. I have docker inside the raspberry pi but the database is in windows. have you idea why this doesnt work?

Comment: I did ping to my machine from the raspberry pi and it can't do it.. I will fix this.

Comment: Check is all necessary ports on your machine is open and not occupied by anything else

Comment: yes now I have disabled the windows firewall and now works